# WSL Connect to MySQL Server 8 on Windows Doesn't Work

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

MySQL Workbench and MySQL server 8 is installed in Windows.  In my WSL2 prompt, I installed the MySQL 8 client.  I want to connect to the MySQL server from WSL2.

When I try `mysql -u root -p  -h 127.0.0.1` I get

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

On WSL I have "mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))" installed.  If I just try `mysql localhost` I get

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I believe this is because I don't have the MySQL server installed on WSL just in Windows.  I had this working a few days ago but then I had a Windows auto-update and I could no longer connect.

Answer (score 1):

Use windows local ip address instead of 127.0.0.1